# Parallax CSS, white space block

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have the following code:

```
<div class="section parallax light-translucent-bg parallax-bg-6">

.parallax-bg-6 {
    background-image: url("../images/parallax-bg-6.jpg");
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: 50% -100px;    
    transition: 0s linear;
    transition-property: background-position;
}
```

It works relatively ok in normal browser, but on touch screen effect of scrolling is gone and horizontal white block appears as well. 
Any ideas how to get rid of white block?

Comment: Way too little info... We'd need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that. But most probably it has something to do either with differences in screen dimensions, or (more likely) problems with touchscreens not (always) sending conventional scroll events.

Comment: sorry, will post more details if I get stuck next time. already resolved it, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

ok, turns out I had style on another div with background-position defined.